# id="" doesn't turn orange in Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzyag.png) my code in Visual Studio Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <button>id = "button"</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why the color doesn't change. It doesn't seem to recognize the code. What's wrong?

Comment: Take a look at w3's HTML tutorials for more help: https://www.w3schools.com/html/

Answer (score 1):

In HTML [`id`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp) should be written between (`<` + the tag name +  ) and (the closing `>`), not inside, *e.g.*:

```
<button id="button"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the screenshot of the syntax
[image: Code is Here]